# How to loop through XML nodes and child nodes using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm currently having an issue with looping through XML nodes and displaying their child elements.

Here is what the XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<monday>
    <employee>
        <name>Employee 1</name>
        <startTime>12 PM</startTime>
        <endTime>3:30 PM</endTime>
        <skills>Web Development, Graphic Design</skills>
        <programs>Sublime Text</programs>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Employee 2</name>
        <startTime>10 AM</startTime>
        <endTime>2 PM</endTime>
        <skills>Graphic Design</skills>
        <programs>Illustrator, Photoshop</programs>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Employee 3</name>
        <startTime>12:30 PM</startTime>
        <endTime>3:30 PM</endTime>
        <skills>Social Media</skills>
        <programs>Facebook, Twitter, Instagram</programs>
    </employee>
</monday>
```

The algorithm I'm aiming for is:

1. Within root element (`monday`), go into firstChild element (`employee`)
2. Loop through each child element of `employee` (`name`, `startTime`, `endTime`, `skills`, `programs`)
3. For each child element, write text to HTML document
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for each `employee` element until iteration reaches lastChild element

So far, I am only able to iterate and write *only one element* of each employee. Here's the code for the `name` element:

```
// loads XML file
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // for IE 5/6
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open("GET","assets/" + today + ".xml",false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
document.write("XML document loaded into an XML DOM Object." + "<br><br>"); // confirms XML file is loaded


// iterates through employees and displays their information
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {                  // line 1
    document.write(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

The output:

```
Employee 1
Employee 2
Employee 3
```

I've tried nesting another for loop within `// line 1`, however that results in nothing displayed in the output.

My goal for the correct output is:

```
Employee 1
Start Time: 12 PM
End Time: 3:30 PM
Skills: Web Development, Graphic Design
Programs: Sublime Text, Dreamweaver

Employee 2
Start Time: 11 AM
End Time: 32 PM
Skills: Graphic Design
Programs: Illustrator, Photoshop

Employee 3
Start Time: 12:30 PM
End Time: 3:30 PM
Skills: Social Media
Programs: Facebook, Twitter, Instagram
```

If you have any questions, I'll answer them the best I can!

Thank you ahead of hand!

Comment: are you opposed to converting your xml to json? that would make this problem much more straight forward

Comment: @BirgitMartinelle The reason why I'm using XML opposed to JSON is organizational/structural purposes. Also, I feel using XML will be easier to share with colleagues and can be utilized by a wider variety of other languages/programs (i.e. python, Excel, etc.)

Comment: I didn't mean to change the format that your service returns - but actually convert it, after you receive the data - there are some plugins (like http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/) that convert xml to json for you - just for use in javascript - if you were to "feed" your data to a html-template or similar having json would make your life easier in the html/js universe ... if that's not the case ignore me ;)

Answer (score 3):

Attaching the root of your loop on `employee` rather than `name` would be better for nested loops (which is what this solution will use):

```
var employees = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("employee"); //outputs array of employees

for (employeeIndex = 0; employeeIndex  < employees.length; employeeIndex++) {
    var empDetails = employees[employeeIndex].children; //outputs array of details

    for (detailIndex = 0; detailIndex < empDetails.length; detailIndex++) {
        document.write(employees[employeeIndex].childNodes[detailIndex].nodeValue);
    }

    document.write("<br>");
}
```

I also noticed the container for each `employee` set of nodes is a day of the week. In the case where you want to iterate through every day of the week, you can create another nest outside of `employeeIndex` to loop through a `dayIndex` of sorts.